# Differentiable limit theorem for sequences of multivariate functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have the following theorem.

> Let ${f_n}$ be differentiable functions on the interval $[a, b]$ such
> that ${f_n(x_0)}$ is convergent for some $x_0 \in [a, b]$. If there is
> $g : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'_n→ g$ uniformly on $[a, b]$,
> then there is $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n→ f$ uniformly
> on $[a, b]$ and $f' = g$.

A proof can be found e.g. [here (Theorem 13.8, p. 289)](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).

Can this theorem be translated to multivariate functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ in a meaningful way? I.e. is there a similar theorem which uses the Jacobian matrix? I am trying to apply the proof on multivariate functions but I'm not sure if I might miss something.

Comment: The hypotheses imply that the mean value inequality holds so I think Rudin's proof, for example, goes through virtually unchanged.